# Where are Passcode Settings for ios 9.2.1 on iphone 5c

Tags: ios, iphone

The location for these options is a mystery.

Related questions show "General | Touch ID and Passcode" . But my phone only has

```
Sounds
Passcode
```

The latter only allows changing the passcode .. but has no other settings. So where are those passcode configuration settings?

Comment: Per another question you commented and I replied: You have an iPhone 5c  that does NOT have Touch ID, therefor you will not have "Touch Id" options.

Comment: Also, perhaps your confusing your phone asking for the passcode to enter passcode settings as a prompt to change the passcode... It's not. Upon entering Settings > Passcode you will be required to enter your current passcode... That first entry is not for a new passcode.

Comment: @Tyson  Yours is the correct answer. That interface *is* confusing. I awarded to the other person Ryan since it was kinda close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to passcode, then "change passcode", you will have these options while entering a new passcode.